# How can I avoid ZAP SQL Injection alerts if my application is already secured against that attack?

Tags: java, spring, security, sql-injection, zap

I have been reported from my QA team that our application can be attacked using SQL Injection. However, any of our queries are created dynamically, we user an API for doing queries similar to Hibernate and we always prepare the statements before executing the queries and we don't use stored procedures. 
The QA team is using ZAP to scan the application. So, what I need to do for avoiding ZAP SQL Injection alerts?

Comment: I cannot answer specifically about disabling ZAP SQL Injection alerts, though the documentation seems to indicate that you would do so by disabling those tests via the appropriate scan policy.  I do suggest, however, that you press your QA team for details of the SQL injection vulnerabilities that ZAP reports -- in the form of testable cases -- so as to verify by *testing*, rather than by reasoning and belief, that the alerts are false positives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All automated scanners can report false positives.
Someone needs to evaluate if the issues reported are false positives or real issues.

If they are false positives then you can either:

- change the [threshold for the specific rule to High](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-core-help/wiki/HelpUiDialogsScanpolicy#threshold)
- change the threshold to Off so that it doesnt run
- create [context alert filters](https://github.com/zaproxy/zap-extensions/wiki/HelpAddonsAlertFiltersAlertFilter) to automatically change them to False Positives

Please also raise a ZAP issue so that we can see if we can fix the code so that false positives are not reported.

Simon (ZAP Project Lead)

Comment: Thanks @Psiinon for your answer, I have talked with QA and agreed to handle the SQL Injection alerts as medium and filter the users inputs just in case. We are going to raise a ZAP issue so we can help you to improve you product.